# How should I manage dependencies in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

I've got a question about dependencies management.
Have a look at the example:

```
MyApp.controller("MyController", ["$scope", "$document", "$timeout", "SomeService",
function(scope, doc, timeout, service){

   /*Some Code here*/

}]);
```

As you can see, the dependencies list + function statement need a lot of writing and it looks a little bit messy.
I know, that I could put all this 'array' in some variable and then inject it inside the controller definition but I don't think, that it's the best idea.
How can I make controller definition with dependencies more clear? Should I deal with RequireJS or something like that?

Thanks!

Comment: I wonder why you are concerned about this. For me this a really good style, all dependencies are listed and you can easily find them.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here best guidelines ever for angularJS

https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

RequireJS comes in handy if you have a ton of routes and pages and you don't want to compress all of your controllers, services, directives, filters etc. together and want to break out your dependencies by path.

The tradeoff here is that this approach is worth the effort only if the level of complexity and size of payload is very high e.g. If you have ten routes, two of which have 100KB of JS, with the rest have 30KB of corresponding JS, and you don't want to serve the 130KB on pageload, considering the the user won't be accessing the 100KB route all the time.

If it is a straightforward application, then RequireJS is not required in most cases (NotRequiredJS. Sorry). It's relatively complicated to implement. But if you're looking at lots of scalability (ideally if you have lots of time, you SHOULD), then you might want to consider RequireJS.